# Mark a method or a function as dev-only in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, webpack

Is there a ready to use way to mark some method or function inside my TypeScript code as for development/debug only, so that it doesn't go into production code when compiled with Webpack?

Something like as comments are cut out of the code.

I have some functions I use sometimes to debug the app, but not used in production. I would like to not comment them out for production because someone else in the team can decide to remove this code as outdated when see it commented.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript does not have a way of doing this out the box, but you can achieve it by using a task runner, such as [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and using a plugin like [this](https://github.com/massick/gulp-strip-code).

I've not really used Webpack before, but I found a plugin that allows you to remove functions from code [here](https://github.com/yahoo/strip-loader).

Answer (score 0):

For methods, that sounds tricky. For functions, it's pretty easy with the Define plugin that comes packaged with Webpack.

1) Surround the code you want gone in production with

```
if (ENV_MODE === 'dev') {
   ...
}
```

2) In your config file, use this inside the plugins array:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'ENV_MODE': "'prod'" // or "'dev'"
})
```

3) Then pipe the output to uglify using

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin
```

that will remove dead code like the if statements that now look like `if ('prod' === 'dev')`